# Alternative to using eval to call slightly different function names?

Tags: javascript

My question was going to be how to do this at all but I came across `eval` which seems to work. I'm told `eval` is evil and the explanations for why went way over my head so my question is:

Is there anything wrong with using `eval` like this, or other ways to do it at all?

```
var condition1=false;
var condition2=true;
var condition3=false;
//etc

if (condition1){x = "1"}
else if (condition2){x = "2"}
else if (condition3){x = "3"};
//etc

var thing1= 11;
var thing2= 22;
var thing3= 33;
//etc

eval ("thing" + x)
```

Comment: `eval()` is not the way to do this. Use [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead.

Comment: Anytime you're `snip`ing your variables in the interest of brevity, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best solution would be to replace all of those variables with an array:

```
thing = [11, 22, 33 ...];
```

then you can just do :

```
thing[x];  // either change your code to zero indexed or subtract 1 here
```

If the variables are global, you could also do this:

```
window["thing"+x];
```

But ideally you would not want these to be global.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an object called `things`

```
var things = {
   "1": 11,
   "2": 22,
   "3": 33
}
```

Then you can refer to a thing with

```
things[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building the strings to be `eval()`'ed yourself, there isn't any real danger involved. Things start getting nasty when you start `eval()`'ing user input.

I'd recommend arrays though. So you could just do this:

```
var conditions=[false, true, false];
for(var i=0;i<conditions.length;i++)
    if(condition[i])x=i+1; //i=0, 1, 2, ...; x=1, 2, 3, ...
eval("thing"+x+"()"); //don't forget the "()"!
```